# TypeError: array[i].call is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, three.js

My code is :

```
$(function() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});

    renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;


    var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
    scene.add(axis);

    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 5);
    var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");
    grid.setColors(color, 0x000000);
    scene.add(grid);

    var Ground_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 0.1, 20 );
    var Ground_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0xa0adaf,
        shininess: 150,
        specular: 0xffffff,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading
    } );

    var ground = new THREE.Mesh( Ground_geometry, Ground_material );
    ground.scale.multiplyScalar( 3 );
    ground.castShadow = false;
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( ground );

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
    scene.add( ambient );

    spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
    spotLight.position.set( 10, 10, 15 );
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 8;
    spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 30;
    spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
    spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = false;
    spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
    spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
    spotLight.name = 'Spot Light';
    scene.add( spotLight );

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', renderer );

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x456574 ,
        shininess: 150,
        specular: 0x222222,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
    });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

    cube.position.x = 0;
    cube.position.y = 0;
    cube.position.z = 0;

    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.x = 40;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 40;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);


    $(window).resize(function(){
        SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    });

});
```

I am getting an error that says : TypeError: array[i].call is not a function 

 and is pointing to line 7484 of three.js library. 
I have included the three.js library using:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.js"></script>
```

So as you can see, its the v73 and I haven't touched the code. What could be the problem?

The error only comes after screen is clicked and then mouse pointer is dragged, so it must have got to do with that piece of code.

Comment: can you see any stack trace for the error, so you can trace it back to which line of _your_ code is triggering it?

Comment: No, nothing like that is being shown except for this :Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. and Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. which is just deprecated function info.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at three.js:7484 and inspect the array. It will give you a clue as to what is causing the problem. The code is clearly in the process to trigger events and the only event you have in this code is the `change` event. It is possible that your `renderer` is misconfigured, but I suspect the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: putting the breakpoint makes the code not run I guess, because the click and drag doesn't work after that. It isn't pointing to some other piece of code or doing anything else

Comment: Also I have tried the same setting of renderer on other piece of code too, and there it worked, so I dont think thats the problem here

Comment: `controls.addEventListener( 'change', renderer );` does not make much sense. renderer is an object that has a render function that takes a scene and a camera as arguments. The eventlistener does not know how to use the "renderer".

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you want the scene to render when OrbitControls sends a change event, you'll have to change the code to:

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
.
.
.
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```