# ThreeJS Trouble with OrbitControls and animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I am having trouble with implementing OrbitControls with the animation I want to play for my scene. Here is the basics of what I have for adding OrbitControls to my AngularJS component:

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
  scene: THREE.Scene;
  camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  controls: THREE.OrbitControls;

  constructor() {
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
  }

  //scene defined in function...

  createControls() {
     this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
     this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
  }

  //model defined in function....


   render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.render);

      //simple animation
      this.model.rotation.z += .01;

      //this.controls.update();

      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
```

When I run my code, I get a black screen until I click on it, and it then starts the animation. The console shows only these violations:

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See <URL>
```

```
[Violation] 'load' handler took 458ms
```

But when I remove `this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);` from  `createControls`, it gives me no console errors but my scene remains black, even when I click on it.

I believe the problem may be because I'm making OrbitControls change according to `render` which is also responsible for the animation, but I'm not completely sure.

I've looked through these related SO questions but I couldn't find a solution:
[Three.js + OrbitControls - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204203/three-js-orbitcontrols-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-render-of)

[TypeError: array[i].call is not a function Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084134/typeerror-arrayi-call-is-not-a-function-error)

I'd appreciate any suggestions to fix this issue!

**Edit:**
Here's how I called my methods:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.createScene();
        this.createLights();
        this.createControls();
        this.createModel();
    }
```

Comment: The scene remains black until you click the screen because you do not call the render function until the orbitControls detects a change (which happens when you click the scene). Try calling the render function once after the these scene is set up.

Comment: @2pha Thank you for the response. I tried changing the order of calling `createControls()` as I added to my question after creating my model but I still have the same issue. Would there be another way to call `render()` after my scene is set up?

Comment: You will want to call render once right after your component has by drawn to the screen, this would start your render loop. I have no angular experience, but I would assume there is some sort of lifecycle method as there is with other frameworks like react, vue etc.

Comment: Ah ok I think I figured it out! I didn't end up using one of Angular's lifecycle methods that you have suggested but it did help me realize I needed to have a separate call for render function. I found this post that actually helped since they had a seperate method to call the requestAnimationFrame before OrbitControls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537364/threejs-creating-plane-that-moves-smoothly
Thank you for your help!